# Multiple test environments flutter with cloud VM

Tags: flutter, git, deployment, devops

I have a Flutter application that runs a file called server.js as the backend, which links to a cloud VM owned by my university.

At the moment, if multiple people are working on server.js, then when you run "flutter run" from your branch, it'll take your frontend code, but it will take whatever server.js version was last pushed (from any branch).

I don't know if there is someway to configure it so that if you run "flutter run", it'll just take the server.js file on your branch. Or does this require having multiple VMs set up?

This is the YAML, please ignore the fact it says heroku - it used to be hosted there, but it is now hosted on this cloud VM.

```
variables:
    HEROKU_APP_NAME: "room-booking-backend"
    HEROKU_PRODUCTION_KEY: $HEROKU_PRODUCTION_KEY

stages:         
  - production

backend-deploy:
  stage: production
main && pm2 restart all'
    - cd server
    - pm2 kill
    - pm2 start server.js
```